# jspm duplicate identifier issues

Tags: node.js, typescript, systemjs, jspm

Got a typescript project set up with NPM. And a general group of starter packages. typescript, angular, jquery, bootstrap, lodash, blah blah blah beneath node_modules and I start prototyping client/server apps.

The million dollar question, how do I get es6 & import support.

So I chose SystemJS and JSPM

ok at this point some packages are installed in node_modules

and I choose to get es6 and import support by installing packages with jspm for those packages I am interested in already under node_modules

But I have at runtime unending error TS2300 duplicate identifier

I piggybacked the node_module installs with jspm syntax

Is there a solution to this massive amount of duplication of identifiers?

Comment: if i am going to use JSPM to import and use lodash then I need to install it into lodash package tracking setup... is it even valid to have lodash installed in bower, npm, or tsd for that matter. Will these other installed packages at these other locations cause this error? If YES... then what is the best practice. Thank You

Comment: Did you try `npm dedupe`?